# Change Kubernetes cluster ip range

Tags: kubernetes

We have setup a Kubernetes cluster with a specific `service-cluster-ip-range`. Now, this range is fully used with IP addresses, so we cannot create new services. When trying to do so, we get the following error:

```
Warning  ProvisioningFailed  2s    persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "glusterfs-storage": failed to create volume: failed to create endpoint/service default/glusterfs-dynamic-gluster-vol-mongodb-data-03: error creating service: Internal error occurred: failed to allocate a serviceIP: range is full
```

We must increase or change the cluster IP range.

We havn't found any documentation on how to change the cluster IP range. Is that even possible? What would be the steps to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of CNI do you use in your cluster?

Comment: We use Weave Net.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the cluster ip service range by modifying the /etc/kubernetes/manifest/kube-controller-manager.yaml file. However, you should cordon off the affected nodes and stop all delete all services/deployments so they can get recreated. You may need to change the setting of your cni plugin. I use Calico and it needed to change the cluster CIDR but not the service ip range. After changing the port; be sure to restart kubelet.

Answer (score 0):

Check [official documentation](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/tasks/ipam/configuring-weave/)

The default configurations for both Weave Net and Docker use  [Private Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), whose addresses are never found on the public Internet, and subsequently reduces the chance of IP overlap. However, it could be that you or your hosting provider are using some of these private addresses in the same range, which will cause a clash.

If after  `weave launch`, the following error message appears:

```
Network 10.32.0.0/12 overlaps with existing route 10.0.0.0/8 on host.
ERROR: Default --ipalloc-range 10.32.0.0/12 overlaps with existing route on host.
You must pick another range and set it on all hosts.
```

As the message indicates, the default range that Weave Net would like to use is  `10.32.0.0/12`  - a 12-bit prefix, where all addresses start with the bit pattern 000010100010, or in decimal everything from 10.32.0.0 through 10.47.255.255.

However, your host is using a route for  `10.0.0.0/8`, which overlaps, since the first 8 bits are the same. In this case, if you used the default network for an address like  `10.32.5.6`  the kernel would never be sure if this meant the Weave Net network of  `10.32.0.0/12`  or the hosting network of  `10.0.0.0/8`.

If you are sure the addresses you want are not in use, then explicitly setting the range with  `--ipalloc-range`  in the command-line arguments to  `weave launch`  on all hosts forces Weave Net to use that range, even though it overlaps. Otherwise, you can pick a different range, preferably another subset of the  [Private Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). For example 172.30.0.0/16.